# Type '"ProfileScreen"' is not assignable to type '"MainScreen"'

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I try to understand how to use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) with TypeScript... I followed [their official manual](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript) for TypeScript, so I've declared all required types:

```
export type MainStackParamList = {
  HomeScreen: undefined
  MapScreen: undefined
  PostScreen: undefined
  ChatScreen: undefined
  ProfileScreen: undefined
}

export type RootStackParamList = {
  MainScreen: NavigatorScreenParams<MainStackParamList>
  SettingsScreen: undefined
  SignInScreen: undefined
  SignUpScreen: undefined
  SplashScreen: undefined
}

export type RootScreenProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, T>

export type MainScreenProps = CompositeScreenProps<
  RootScreenProps<'MainScreen'>,
  MaterialBottomTabScreenProps<MainStackParamList>
>
```

My app screen structure is below:

- App: `Stack.Navigator`

  - `MainScreen`: `Tab.Navigator`

    - `ProfileScreen`
    - ...
  - `SettingsScreen`
  - ...

**App.tsx:**

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>()

const App = ({injector}: Props) => {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen">
            {props => <MainScreen injector={injector} {...props} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SettingsScreen"
            component={SettingsScreen}
          />
          // Other screens
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  )
}
```

**MainScreen.tsx:**

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()

const MainScreen = ({injector}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ProfileScreen">
        {props => <ProfileScreen injector={injector} {...props} />}
      </Tab.Screen>
      // Other screens
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

**ProfileScreen.tsx:**

```
type Props = {
  injector: ProfileScreenInjector
} & MainScreenProps

const ProfileScreen = ({injector, navigation}: Props) => {
  return // Profile view
}
```

In the `ProfileScreen` (a child of the `MainScreen`) I need to call an outer navigator (`Stack.Navigator`), a something like `navigation.navigation('SettingsScreen')`. However, I get an error in the `MainScreen.tsx`:

```
Type '{ route: RouteProp<ParamListBase, "ProfileScreen">; navigation: any; injector: MainScreenInjector; }' is not assignable to type 'MainScreenProps'.
  Types of property 'route' are incompatible.
    Type 'RouteProp<ParamListBase, "ProfileScreen">' is not assignable to type 'RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "MainScreen">'.
      Type 'RouteProp<ParamListBase, "ProfileScreen">' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ key: string; name: "MainScreen"; path?: string | undefined; }>'.
        Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
          Type '"ProfileScreen"' is not assignable to type '"MainScreen"'.ts(2322)
```

What am I doing wrongly? How to declare types for screens in a nested navigator to they could call the root one?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've realised my mistake, I was needed to change the declaration of `MainScreenProps` type a little as below:

```
export type MainScreenProps<T extends keyof MainStackParamList> =
  CompositeScreenProps<
    MaterialBottomTabScreenProps<MainStackParamList, T>,
    RootScreenProps<keyof RootStackParamList>
  >
```

Then to specify a right key for the generic type in `ProfileScreen` props:

```
type Props = {
  injector: ProfileScreenInjector
} & MainScreenProps<'ProfileScreen'>
```

And finally to add a missing generic type for the `Tab` definition in the `MainScreen`:

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator<MainStackParamList>()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Stack.Screen name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen} />
```

Bu the component uses another screen params

```
// SignInScreen.tsx
type SignInScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<
  NavigationRootParamList,
  'SignUpScreen' //  this here should be SignInScreen
>;
```

Hence, you get the error `Type '"SignInScreen"' is not assignable to type '"SignUpScreen"'.ts(2322)`